# Where do I attach the grounding conductor to my bedroom light fixture?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, grounding

I have a problem, I broke the center piece that holds the glass part on my light fixture in my room. I purchased a replacement and removed the two screws holding my fixture on to the ceiling. Now I need to put it back together. I see that there is the ground wire but I did not notice where was attached to. Does that wire need to be screwed in with the centerpiece?

Comment: Can you post a link to a photo of the light fitting. Without being able to see the light fitting any answer is little more than a guess,.

Comment: Is the light fixture attached to a metal, or plastic box?  Does the light fixture, or the fixture strap have a green screw anywhere on them?

Comment: I'm VTC NARQ as OP hasn't responded with critical information.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear exactly what your situation is, and I'm not sure if you have a ground in the supply, or on the fixture, or both.  So I'll try to cover all possible situations.

## No grounds

If there are not ground wires, do nothing. You're done.

## Metal box

### Ground in supply, ground on fixture

If there is a ground in the feeder cable, and a ground wire or screw on the fixture.  Attach both the supply ground and the fixture ground to the box, using either a green screw or a ground clip

[image: Ground Screw][image: Ground Clip]

If the ground screw, or clip is not rated to accept multiple wires (most aren't). Use a grounding twist-on wire connector to connect all the ground wires, then attach the pigtail to the box using a green screw or ground clip.

[image: Grounding twist-on wire connector]

### Ground in supply, no ground on fixture

If you have a metal box, a ground wire in the feeder cable, but no ground wire/screw attached to the fixture.  Attach the feeder ground wire to the metal box using a green screw or a ground clip.

In this case, when the fixture is attached to the box it should be bonded through the attachment method.

### No ground in supply, ground on fixture

If there is no ground in the feeder cable, but there is a ground wire or screw attached to the fixture.  Attach the ground wire of the fixture to the box, using a green screw or ground clip.  In this situation the outlet *may* be feed with Type AC or MC cable, and the box *may* be grounded on the exterior of the box. Or the outlet may not be grounded at all, in which case the fixture ground is useless.

## Nonmetallic box

### Ground in supply, ground on fixture

If you have a ground in the feeder cable, and  a ground screw or wire on the fixture.  Use a twist-on wire connector, or crimp connector to connect all grounds together.

### Ground in supply, no ground on fixture

If there is a ground wire in the feeder cable, but no ground screw or wire on the fixture. If a fixture strap is used, attach the ground wire to the fixture strap using a green screw or ground clip.

[image]

If a fixture strap is not used, leave the ground wire folder neatly in the back of the box.

#### No ground in supply, ground on fixture

If you don't have a ground in the feeder cable, but there is a ground wire or screw on the fixture.  Don't make any ground connections.