# vanity lighting

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I'm replacing an old hollywood bar light. I therefore have to install a box as there wasn't one before. I bought the box and connector. I'm concerned about grounding the box. How do I ground it and can you please let me know if the box and connectors look correct?

Thank you!
Kathleen[image: box]
[image]

Comment: Most lighting fixtures use octagonal (or round) fixture boxes, you will see than listed as 4/O. The ones for insertion and attachment on existing walls, with clamps to hold them like the box in your picture, are called "old work" boxes. How was your previous fixture wired? Do you intend to fish wires through the wall? How is it that you had a wall-mounted fixture with no box?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it The box was likely integrated into the old fixture, so there's just a hole in the wall for the cable to pass through.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/27052/33)

Comment: Those look like conduit connectors.  Is the box fed by nonmetallic cable, conduit, or armored cable.

Comment: Yup, those are BX connectors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I attach the grounding conductor to my bedroom light fixture?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26927/where-do-i-attach-the-grounding-conductor-to-my-bedroom-light-fixture)

Answer (score 1):

One (or more) of the holes in the back of the box should be threaded, so you can use a grounding screw to attach a grounding conductor to the box.

[image: ground screw]

Alternatively, you could use a grounding clip to attach the grounding conductor to the edge of the box.

[image: grounding clip]

If there's no grounding conductor currently at the box, then you'll have to get one there. You can either pull a new one in from the panel, or connect the grounding conductor of a nearby circuit.

Comment: Do not use a sheet metal screw, they will not engage enough threads to hold reliably.  Those particular green screws are 10-32 fine-thread; quality boxes will have a hole already tapped for 10-32.  Any 10-32 screw will do, but a bag of these is a buck and you won't confuse it with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is armored cable. Here is a photo of the wires. There is no grounding wire currently.
Thanks,
Kathleen

[image: wires]